# PowerShell - How to get names of piped variables

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out something in powershell using piping.

I have something like this:

```
Get-Project -All | %{ $_.Name }
```

*Note: I know `%{}` = `ForEach{}`*

`Get-Project -All` is a NuGet command which returns all project in current solution.

This works for me, but I would like to find out all available variables that get piped through. I only know `$_.Name` is one of them as I can see from an example online.

When I run `Get-Project -All` I get the following output

```
ProjectName   Type   FullName  
-----------   ----   --------
ABC           C#     C:\SolutionDir\Category\ABC.csproj
```

Now inside my pipe I found the following variables:

```
$_.Name = ABC
$_.ProjectName = Category/ABC
$_.Type = C#
$_.FullName = C:\SolutionDir\Category\ABC.csproj
```

Now what I don't understand is

1. The "Table" output of `Get-Project -All` has a header of `ProjectName` with value of `ABC`. But inside the pipe `$_.ProjectName = Category/ABC and`$_.Name = ABC`. Are they unrelated?
2. If I didn't see the example online mentioning `$_.Name` I would of never known about this variable. Is there some way of getting all available variables?

**Note:**

`Get-Project -All | %{ Get-Variable }` does not return any of the above mentioned variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the pipeline, it's the entire object created, in this case `Get-Project`, that is sent through it. To see all members of an object, use `Get-Member`.

So in your case, you can use `Get-Project -All | Get-Member` to see all the properties and methods of the object being returned.

Comment: And to save on typing there's a standard alias `gm` which you can use: `Get-Project -All | gm`